# UIView not receiving touch events but view below it are

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView that I hide / unhide when needed. Everything was fine, but something has changed and I am unsure what. When I tap the UIView that I unhide, the views underneath it receive the events and not the view that is onto of all the other views.

I've set the view up in storyboard and the only code I use with it is to hide or unhide it.

Here is what My views look like in Storyboard:

[image]

Sort view is the view that is not receiving touch events.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?
Thanks!

Comment: So it was working, and now it is not, what did you change in the interim? Can you post the code where you're trying to receive the touch events.

Comment: The only thing changed was auto layout constraints that I had to setup again. I can't recall anything else that I changed that would give this issue. The view has IBOutlets connected to my viewController. I've checked those and they still show as connected. However, tapping the buttons (IBOutlets) on the UIView does not trigger them. However my UITableView below the UIView still scrolls if I try scrolling. Its very odd..

Comment: check in Interface Builder view property `userInteractionEnabled`

Comment: I've checked and its set to enabled.

Comment: @Tander check `IBAction`s from buttons are still connected? Or how do you trigger them?

Comment: They are still connected.

Comment: Add background color and check your view's frame maybe your view frame is low then subview's frame.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve this. Problem was the auto layout constraints. I have no idea why they would stop the touches event. I removed all constraints and reset them.